# Probabilty: Given a random 12/50 options, I get to choose 5 of the random 12. How many options should I prepare for?

Tags: probability

My professor will give us 12 out of a possible 50 topics from a list we have, and we have to write about 5 of the 12 he chooses from the list of 50. How many topics do I have to know to ensure I will be able to write about 5 of them?

A formula to solve this problem with an explanation would be appreciated, as I would like to apply this question to different situations and understand what exactly is going on. Thanks!

Comment: The question as it is doesn't need probability, it is answerable by combinatorial considerations only (see answer of @user133281). The question would be more interesting if you asked about a 93% (say) chance on the assumption that the professor would choose the questions randomly, independently and equidistributed.

Comment: If you study only $29$ questions there will be $<5\%$ probability that you won't be able to pick $5$ questions out of $12$ to answer. $33-1\%$, $34-0.5\%$, [$37-0.075\%$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%28%28binom%2812%2Ck%29*binom%2838%2C37-k%29%29%2Fbinom%2850%2C37%29%29+for+k%3D0+to+4). So there is not need to study $43$ questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Worst case scenario, all topics you do not know will be on the list. There can be at most $7$ such topics, so you need to know $50-7=43$ of them.

In general, if you have to write about $\ell$ topics on a list of $k$ topics that were chosen by your professor out of $N$ topics, you will need to know $N-(k-\ell)$ of them at least.

Comment: What do you mean by at most $7$ such problems?

Comment: @user19405892: user133281 means that we cannot permit any more than $7$ such problems, because if there are $8$ or more such problems (that the student does not understand), they might all be on the professor's selected $12$, leaving only $4$ that the student can answer.

Comment: Right, we must look at the worst case scenario.